# Trigger when a select occurs

Tags: sql, select, triggers

i have a customer with a ERP wich i don't have programming access, and wants to do a special trigger when a item is selected. The problem is that the ItemID is nowhere kept when chosen, only when whole sale is kept, and the trigger should happen before that.
This is a novice question for sure, but this value must be kept somewhere right ?
When i do a audit do see what happens when the item is chosen inside the ERP it only does SELECT statments. Can i do a trigger based on a SELECT ?

Thank you.

Comment: You are not specifying which sql server or version. It might help having that information.

Comment: Its a MSSQL 2008 Express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to create a trigger based on execution of a select query in PL/SQL. Trigger can be created only on INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE.

References :

- https://community.oracle.com/thread/1556647?tstart=0
- http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/18571

Comment: Thank you for the links, helped in finding the answer. The value was kept in another table that i discovered thru audit.